# Export output of sql in Excel using Query

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to export outupt of sql query. But I dont want to do it manually like right click on output and then export. I want to export output in excel in specific directory.

Comment: look at Oracle sqlcli (newer alternative to sqlplus) which lets you set export formats, including csv, which you can open with Excel.  There is no way that I know of to generate a native .xlsx file.

Answer (score 0):

Change filename_excel to

```
filename_excel = [my_directory name '_N' num2str(1) '.xlsx'];
```

where

```
my_directory = 'C:\some\directory\structure\';
```

Alternatively (though use the first solution if possible) you can go:

```
current_dir = cd;
cd my_directory;

filename_excel = [ name '_N' num2str(1) '.xlsx'];
writetable(Table,filename_excel,'Sheet', 3, 'Range','A5');

cd current_dir;
clear current_dir;
```

by @aybybtu